# Using localhost for Secure Canvas URL on Facebook App

Tags: facebook, ssl, canvas, https, facebook-apps

I need to develop a Facebook app, and while I request my SSL certificate, I need to start the project because I have few time to deliver it. 
Is it possible to use `localhost` as the "Secure Canvas URL"? This field requires that the URL begins with `https`, so I don't know the correct way to do it (in the case that using localhost is allowed).

Comment: First of all you need to set up your server to answer HTTPS request. Then you create a self-signed SSL certificate – not sure if that works for the domain name `localhost`, but I’d recommend setting up a local domain, such as `mytest.local` anyway (the `.local` being the important part here), make your server listen to that, and your system resolve it to your local IP address, f.e. via its `hosts` file. And then you tell your browser to accept that self-signed certificate … and you’re good to go.

Comment: please, write it as answer to mark it as valid. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set up your server to answer HTTPS requests.
Then you create a self-signed SSL certificate – not sure if that works for the domain name `localhost`, but I’d recommend setting up a local domain, such as `mytest.local` anyway (the `.local` being the important part here), make your server listen to that, and your system resolve it to your local IP address, f.e. via its `hosts` file.

And then you tell your browser to accept that self-signed certificate … and you’re good to go.